# improve python tail log when a log of data write in one second

Tags: python-3.x, file, logging, tail

I writer a method to tail log

eg

```
def getTailLog(self):

    with open(self.strFileName, 'rb') as fileObj:
        pos = fileObj.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

        try:

            while True:

                if self.booleanGetTailExit:
                    break

                strLineContent = fileObj.readline()
                if not strLineContent:
                    continue
                else:
                    yield strLineContent.decode('utf-8').strip('\n')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

this method can tail log, but will delay even stuck when massive data writer into log file in one second

so how can i repair

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I do not fully understand what you mean by `delay even stuck when massive data writer into log file in one second`.

Your code contains while loop which can potientially run forever. Looks like your code waits for the line to be appended to the end of the file `self.strFileName`. The problem is that it does not just wait. It continuously checks the content of the file. This is so called CPU bound operation which may cause huge delays in reading/writing within the same process (up to 10 seconds for 100 KB binary file from my experience). Python has this behavior because of GIL (global interpreter lock).

To solve your problem you should replace while loop implementation with another one - you may use schedule (at least pauses between consecutive checks) or event driven approach (if you know when new lines are added to the file).